# How to get the next group given a step?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to define a function (it doesn't need to be Python) that would take a number and give the next group given the size of a group.  I'm pretty sure I can write it with an `if` statement, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it with integer math.

```
def next(x, size):
  return ???

for i in range(0,20):
  print(next(i, 3))

# expected
3
3
3
6
6
6
9
9
9
12
12
12
15
15
15
18
18
18
21
21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
def next(x, size):
    return x // size * size + size

for i in range(0,20):
    print(next(i, 3))
```

Output:

```
3
3
3
6
6
6
9
9
9
12
12
12
15
15
15
18
18
18
21
21
```

Comment: what does `//` mean?

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano it's called floor division, it's equivalent to `int(num / othernum)`

Comment: I like this one slightly more than mine because of the floor division operator.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, after a few hacks on repl.it

```
def next(x, size):
  return int(x / size + 1) * size
```

Comment: This doesn't match your current example output.

Comment: Nope. Your current example output in the question description does not include 18 (it skips from 15 to 21), which is also why some people might never have been able to answer this question correctly.